# Как вставить ссылку в кнопку aiogram

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Создаю бота, и вот хочу сделать такой вот результат, как на картинках. Как этого можно добиться? Использую Aiogram.

[image: Вот так выглядит кнопка]
[image: В поля для ввода автоматически вставляется такая запись]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать **InlineKeyboardMarkup** и **InlineKeyboardButton**.
Примерно так:

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button = InlineKeyboardButton('Моя жаба', url='https://google.com')
keyboard.add(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод "switch_inline_query_current_chat"

```
Interaction.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("Моя жаба",
 switch_inline_query_current_chat='Моя жаба'))
```

Вот результат:

[image: Вот результат]

Это написано в документации aiogram https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton